# How to get the current repository?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

how do i get what the current repository is for a directory?

I want to do:

```
SvnInfoEventArgs info;
Uri repos = new Uri("http://my.server/svn/repos");
client.GetInfo(repos, out info);
```

but I don't know what the URI is for the directory as it was previously checked out. How do I get what the URI is for a given checkout location?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to get the repository URI from a folder:

```
     using (var folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
     {
        folderDlg.Description = Resources.SelectBranchFolder;
        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        folderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           string workingPath = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
           using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
           {
              Uri repo = svnClient.GetUriFromWorkingCopy(workingPath);
              if (repo != null)
              {
                 MessageBox.Show("The URI for this folder is " + repo.AbsoluteUri);
              }
              else
              {
                 MessageBox.Show("This is not a working SVN directory.");
              }
           }
        }
     }
```